# Cannot find a key of a std::map with customized compare function

Tags: c++, std

```
#include <cstdio>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct mycmp {
      bool operator()(const int &a, const int  &b) const {
          return abs(a) <= abs(b);
      }
};

int main(){
  map<int, int, mycmp> M1;
  map<int, int> M2;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    M1[i]++;
    M2[i]++;
  }
  cout << (int)(M1.find(4) == M1.end()) << endl;
  cout << (int)(M2.find(4) == M2.end()) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

the output of codes above is

```
1
0
```

which implies can't find the key 4 of M1, while 4 can be found in M2.
But everything looks fine when I use an iterator to iterate M1 like

```
for ( auto &x: M1) cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
```

it outputs

```
0 1
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
```

it seems to be caused by compare function, but why and how?

Comment: Your comparison is not a strict weak ordering, which causes undefined behaviour. In particular, your comparison says that every number is ordered before itself, which is impossible.

Comment: The comparator must return false given two same numbers.

Comment: Your comparator doesn't satisfy [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given two elements `a` and `b` the comparator is used to decide if `a` should come before `b`. If `comp(a,b) == true` then `a` comes before `b`.

The same element cannot be placed before itself. Though, your comparator requires that, because `mycomp(a,a) == true`.

More specifically the comparator must impose a strict weak ordering. The constraints are listed here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare

It says:

> - For all `a`, `comp(a,a)==false`
> - If `comp(a,b)==true` then `comp(b,a)==false`
> - if `comp(a,b)==true` and `comp(b,c)==true` then `comp(a,c)==true`

Your comparator violates the first two. Note that the comparator and sorting do not care at all about equality. Certainly `a==a`, but even if this was not the case (because your elements have some odd `operator==`) `comp(a,a)` must return `false`.

Using a comparator for `sort` or for a `std::map` that does not adhere to the requirements listed in the page linked above results in undefined behavior.